# How show percent(%) when use UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

when use UIWebView,some apps can show percent when load website.
I find some way,but don't work fine,like:

1.use NSUrlConnection get HTML , then use UIWebView load the HTML

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
  theTotalLength = response.expectedContentSize;
}
```

but,sometimes  there have no "expectedContentSize" to get.

2.use private function,but can't post AppStore。this function
[enter link description here](https://github.com/petr-inmite/imtwebview)

someone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `estimatedProgress` property, as detailed [here](http://winxblog.com/2009/02/iphone-uiwebview-estimated-progress/). Note that it is a private function, but according to the guide, there are some apps in the App Store that do use it.

Comment: now,in ios5.0sdk there have no privateFrame.frame.also thanks.